# What is the convention to expose inline C++ operators from a namespace in the standard library?

Tags: c++, stl, namespaces

I'm looking for an official (or at least semi-official) way of exposing my operators in my standard-like library.

For example, I implemented a [string literal operator for int128](https://github.com/m2osw/snapdev/blob/main/snapdev/int128_literal.h) so that way I can write 128 bit integers at compile time. So far, when I implemented operators, I would just put them outside of my namespace to make them all work without a `using namespace snapdev` which would be bad because that would bring everything from that namespace and I sure don't want that.

For literals, I've seen that you can use a `namespace literals` sub-namespace as in the [chrono library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s).

Now, I have many classes that have a corresponding `ostream` operator like in my [matrix](https://github.com/m2osw/snapdev/blob/main/snapdev/matrix.h) implementation:

```
template<class E, class S, class T, class SIZE>
std::basic_ostream<E, S> & operator << (std::basic_ostream<E, S> & out, snapdev::matrix<T, SIZE> const & m)
{
    ...
}
```

Finally, I have a [C++ extension to the `struct timespec`](https://github.com/m2osw/snapdev/blob/main/snapdev/timespec_operations.h) in order to add or subtract or compare values found in a `timespec` structure. I defined inline operators outside of my namespace ("as usual") but I'd like to fix that and move those operators inside a sub-namespace (like the above for `literals`).

Is there a convention for this one in the C++ standard library or boost?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've read [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) already but just have to mention it since you don't in your question. _"These function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup._"

Comment: @TedLyngmo In case of the `struct timespec`, it's from the C standard library, so it's not in a namespace... And for `__int128`, its a compiler defined type (an extension available with gcc/g++). Would the convention be not to use a namespace in those _special_ cases?

Comment: I didn't read the code at github but expect `namespace something { struct timespec_ex : timespec { /* extensions */ }; }` and free functions (in `namespace something`) operating on `timespec_ex`. In that case these should be picked up by ADL.

Answer (score 2):

The conventions that work well for user-defined literals (either putting them in the global namespace, or in a nested namespace which needs to be manually imported with `using namespace`) don't work that well for other operators.

Operators (other than UDL) should either be declared where [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) can reach them (i.e. in the same namespace as the parameter types - which you shouldn't do if the namespace is not under your control), or, if they're in a different namespace, imported individually using `using ...::operator...;` (not `using namespace`, see below).

When you try to declare them in the global namespace, they might be shadowed by operators in nested namespaces:

```
namespace X
{
    struct A {};
}

void operator+(X::A, X::A) {}

namespace Z
{
    struct B {};
    void operator+(B, B) {}

    void foo()
    {
        X::A{} + X::A{}; // error: invalid operands to binary expression ('X::A' and 'X::A')
    }
}
```

The same thing happens (interestingly) when you put them in a nested namespace and try to `using namespace` it:

```
namespace X
{
    struct A {};
}

namespace Y
{
    void operator+(X::A, X::A) {}
}

namespace Z
{
    struct B {};
    void operator+(B, B) {}

    void foo()
    {
        using namespace Y;
        X::A{} + X::A{}; // error: invalid operands to binary expression ('X::A' and 'X::A')
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, because apparently `using namespace` works [*"as if [the names] were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and [target namespace]"*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) (i.e. in this case in the global namespace).

Comment: Okay, that makes sens. How do you declare your own `<<` operators for `std::ostream` since we are not supposed to extend `std`? Just like me? Outside your `namespace` (i.e. _inline_)?

Comment: @AlexisWilke in the same namespace as type you are overloading it for, ADL will then find your operator.

Comment: That works. I've updated my implementation to make use of a class like @TedLyngmo suggested above. Very minimal changes on the outside and all operators work as expected without `using namespace ...`.